# ReactJS ApexChart problem with displaying the correct xlabel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a basic chart from ApexChart and I have a problem with displaying the label correct in percentage.

my code for the xaxis:

```
xaxis: {
      labels: {
        formatter: function (val) {
          return Math.abs(Math.round(val)) + "%"
        }
      },
    },
```

at the moment if the data is at 1% the xaxis displays 0-1% it is possible to change that the xaxis to display 0-100% but the data to reach just to 1%

This is the chart that I am using
https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/bar-charts/basic/

What I have so far:
Here you can see that my data is between 0% - 1% but I want to be 0 - 100% but just 0-1% to be highlighted, to be displayed.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear. Please post the full code of what you've tried and also provide the final result which you want to achieve (maybe with a graphic).

Comment: I just updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the min and max for xaxis to set a range.

```
xaxis: {
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  labels: {
    formatter: function (val) {
      return Math.abs(Math.round(val)) + "%"
    }
  }
}
```